# xpath - if value is less than other value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML feed with `<price>` and `<newprice>` as two values.
What I need is xpath function to display `<newprice>` only if it's smaller value than old `<price>`. If value is not smaller, then not to display anything (or 0 is fine too).

Example:

`<price>88</price><newprice>88</newprice>` result would be '0'
`<price>88</price><newprice>45</newprice>` result would be '45'

In general i want newprice to be visible only if it's smaller value. Otherwise should display be '0'. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps an example input and expected output would be helpful here.

Comment: @Larson I'm afraid the example is not yet clear enough. Also, it is better to add examples by editing your question than writing in comments.

Comment: Sorry, guys just learning on how to use all this. example posted - is it enough?

Comment: Since Jirka has answered the question, I'll only leave this as a comment: http://3v4l.org/op0f5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prices>
    <price>88</price>
    <newprice>88</newprice>
</prices>
```

In xpath 1.0 this could work (returns nothing if new prices is not lower)

```
/prices/newprice[number(.) &lt; number(preceding-sibling::price)]
```

In xpath 2.0 this could be done (returns zero)

```
if (prices/newprice &lt; prices/price) then prices/newprice else 0
```

Comment: thanks Jirka. sorry i am trying to modify someone's else work, so not yet sure on details such as xpath version. i'll test both and let post result here. thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks Jirka and Passerby